# C# Export zip entries from one zipFile to other zipFile

Tags: c#, .net, zip, c#-ziparchive

Has zip file

Task:

1. create target zipFile
2. copy some entries from source to target

Task is solved:
1. open entry.
2. decompress to MemoryStream (sourceStream)
3. create entry (same name as source) on target zipFile
4. open target entry and copy sourceStream

All OK.

Problem: 
very slow, even using two Thread: one read, second write.

Question:
Is there ability to get directly compressed data from source and directly write to target.

can use: IO.Compression or SharpZipLib or Package

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

I use: http://github.com/jaime-olivares/zipstorer

and rewrite ExtractFileAsync to get raw compressed data

and rewrite AddStreamAsync to write raw compressed data without no change in attributes.

speed is maximum